# NextJs API: respond with SSR react page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Goal:

- Respond with server side rendered html from nextjs api

Why i need this:

- I am building custom internal html page editor using react where the page model is represented as JSON. I want to send a page model JSON to the nextjs api, pass it to react component and get the html back.

What i've tried is the api with direct call to `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`:

```
export default (req, res) => {

  const model = req.body.pageModel

  const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <App
        model={model}
      />)

  res.statusCode = HttpStatus.OK
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
  res.end(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html >
    <head></head>
    <body>
        ${body}
    </body>
  </html>
`)
}
```

Question:

Is there a way to reuse nextjs rendering approach instead of `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` and JS string templates so that i am able to specify and use my own `_app.js` and `_page.js` in response to api?

Something like following will suit my needs:

```
const html = next.render(<App model={model}>)
res.end(html)
```

Comment: Have the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

If you're open to ready-to-use solutions, I recommend to look into React rich editors, https://draftjs.org/ being the most popular. They come with a collection of functions and particularly what you need and HTML compatibility.

Comment: Thank you. The page editor i am building will contain the rich text editor inside of it for text elements editing. It is not suitable for page layout builds.